# How to show that the set $W=\{(x,y,z):x+y=0\}$ is a subspace of the vector space $V_3(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let alpha=(x,y,z) and beta=(u,v,w) be any two elements of W.
Then x,y,z,u,v,w are the elements of R and are such that\
                      ($x+u=0).....(1)
                  ($y+v=0)......(2)
                      ($z+w=0).....(3)
$If a,b be any  two elements of R,we have 
         a $\alpha+ b beta=a(x,y,z)+b(u,v,w)
                                   =(ax+bu),(ay+bv),(az+bw)
Now,.  ax+bu+ay+bv+az+bw=a(x+y+z)+b(u+v+w)??

This is the way I did this question,where I went wrong?

Comment: A subset of a vector space needs to fulfill three simple rules in order to be a subspace. Do you know what those rules are?

Comment: Zero vector should be in the set W.

Comment: Good, that's rule 1. Now, _is_ the zero vector in the set $W$?

Comment: Scalar multiplication and vector addition.

Comment: That's rule 2 and 3. So, 2) if you add two vectors from $W$, is the result still always in $W$, no matter which two vectors you added? And 3) if you scale a vector from $W$, is the result in $W$ no matter which vector you started with and which scalar you used? Those are the questions you need to answer. And we would really appreciate it if you edited your question post to show what you have tried for each rule.

Comment: You need to show that it is *closed* under these two operations. Take two elements in W and show that their sum is still in W, similarly for one element multiplied by a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show: if $(x,y,z), (u,v,w) \in W$ and $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$ then

$(x+u,y+v,z+w) \in W$ and $(\alpha x,\alpha y,\alpha z) \in W$.

Comment: You're forgetting $0\in W$. Which assuming your properties is really equivalent to $W\neq\varnothing$, so it's quite trivial. Nevertheless it must be pointed out of a proof is to be complete.